# How do you perform math operation on all dictionaries in a list and return the name key with the highest value?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
players = [{
'name': 'Julio Jones',
   'catches': 99,
   'targets': 157
   },
   {
   'name': 'Davante Adams',
   'catches': 83,
   'targets': 127
   },
   {
   'name': 'Michael Thomas',
   'catches': 149,
   'targets': 185
   },
]
```

For the above dictionary I would like to calculate `catchrate` for each player which is defined as `catchrate = catches/targets`, then I would like to return the name of the player in the list which has the highest `catchrate`, how do I do this?

Comment: What programming language is it this?

Comment: im sorry I would like this for python3

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#max) to get this info.  The `key` parameter tells python how to sort the elements, what value to use when sorting.

```
max_player = max(players, key=lambda p: p['catches']/p['targets'])

print(max_player['name'])
```

Comment: thank you so much, it worked very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
players = [{
'name': 'Julio Jones',
   'catches': 99,
   'targets': 157
   },
   {
   'name': 'Davante Adams',
   'catches': 83,
   'targets': 127
   },
   {
   'name': 'Michael Thomas',
   'catches': 149,
   'targets': 185
   },
]



def getHighestCatchRate(playerList):
    catchRates = []
    for player in playerList:
        catchRates.append(player["catches"] / player["targets"] )

    highestRate = max(catchRates)
    maxPlayerIndex = catchRates.index(highestRate)
    playerName = playerList[maxPlayerIndex]["name"]

    return(playerName)


getHighestCatchRate(players)
```

What we are doing here is that we are appending to a list where we store the catch rates. Since the list is in order of the players, we find the max catchrate from the list and find the index of the max. That index is also the index of the player with the highest catchrate in the "players" list. So we return that player's name. Let me know if you have any questions! And I hope that helps!